# setting the clicked values in spinner in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and my question is about `Spinner`. I have one activity that contains nodes or devices. Clicking on a particular device opens its settings which has spinner. Now, if for example i have three devices a cellphone, tv and a refrigerator. Now long clicking on tv opens its settings which has spinner. And the spinner shows first value tv. Now if i long click on cellphone and its settings gets opened which has a spinner but i should display cellphone on that which is displaying tv.
In short it should display the device name that is selected.

Can anyone please help me out.

I have made an `Arraylist`, an `Arrayadapter`, have declared `Spinner` values too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can set the value using `setSelection (int position)` if you want **animate** the `Spinner` use `setSelection (int position, boolean animate)`

for more details from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29)

Comment: make this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Spinner (DropDown List)**

Open “res/layout/main.xml” file, add two spinner components and a button.

- In “spinner1″, the “android:entries” represents the selection items
  in spinner.
- In “spinner2″, the selection items will be defined in code later.

*File : res/layout/main.xml*

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

*MyAndroidAppActivity.java*

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }

  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

  // get the selected dropdown list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

*CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java*

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Learnt alot from this :)